# How can I issue a Google image search request via cURL?

Tags: curl, post, jpeg, google-image-search

I'm trying to do a reverse image search by file upload using cURL. To that end I've opened the Firefox network tab in the console and selected "copy as cURL" on the respective POST request. This gives me

```
curl 'https://www.google.de/searchbyimage/upload' -H 'User-Agent: ...' \
-H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8' \
-H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5' --compressed -H 'Referer: https://www.google.de/' \
-H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------10498230641660457283476667604' \
-H 'Cookie: ...' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1' -H 'TE: Trailers' \
--data '@/path/to/image.jpg'
```

User-Agent and Cookies have been omitted. `@/path/to/image.jpg` in the `--data` parameter was added by me because Firefox's copy just read `--data ''`.

In response to this I do get redirected successfully. But the page is almost empty and just reads "Search by image is unavailable. Please try again in a few hours." - rather opaque. Also it doesn't seem like cURL is actually transmitting the image in the first place.

Where might I have erred?

Comment: Is this information useful for your situation? https://github.com/tanaikech/goris

Comment: This looks like it might be useful. At the very least I can just read the source code.

As an aside, I take it you are the author of this project? I'd correct the occurrences of `iamge` to `image` in the project readme.

Comment: Yes. This is my repository. And thank you for the information. I had never been able to notice about it. I modified it. Thank you so much.

Comment: i tried this some years back, but ended up using Bing image search instead, because google had made it *really* difficult to accomplish, but Bing made it trivial.

Answer (score 1):

2023 : Google changed to Google Lens

```
curl -F encoded_image=@/path/to/image.jpg https://lens.google.com/upload
```

It seems the form in the website define the image as boundary data when uploaded, but it works as a simple file from outside the website as well.